# Let $K_0$ denote the prime subfield of $K$ then $\text{Gal}(K/K_0)=\text{Aut}(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $K_0$ denote the prime subfield of $K$ then
>   $\text{Gal}(K/K_0)=\text{Aut}(K)$.

This is a statement in the book I am looking at, it is given without proof or further explanation. I don't see why this is true. $\text{Gal}(K/K_0)$ has to fix the elements of $K_0$ but why do all automorphims of $K$ have to fix $K_0$ how do we know we can't find an automorphism of $K$ that doesn't fix $K_0$?

I then tried to prove $\text{Gal}(K/K_0)=\text{Aut}(K)$, clearly $\text{Gal}(K/K_0) \subset\text{Aut}(K)$ by defintition of $\text{Gal}(K/K_0)$ but I can't prove the other inclusion.

I feel like I need to use the fact that $K_0$ is the prime subfield (the smallest subfield of $K$) somehow but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $f \in Aut(K)$ then $f(1)=1$. Use this to prove that $f$ fixes $K_0$.

Comment: In the meantime you will meet objects, where you cannot touch any elements...

Comment: How do we know $f(1)=1$? Is it because it's a field homomorphism? Also I don't know what $K_0$ "looks like" so I'm unsure how to prove it fixes $K_0$

Comment: The restriction of $f$ to $K \setminus \{0\}$, which is a group with respect to multiplication, is a group automorphism.  What do group homomorphisms do?

Comment: @ChrisB $$f(1)=f(1 \cdot 1)= f(1) f(1) \,.$$ Now, since $f(1) \neq f(0)=0$, $f(1)$ is invertible, and then you can multiply both sides of the first equality by its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

- The set of fixed points of an automorphism $K \to K$ is a subfield of $K$
- The prime field is the intersection of all subfields of $K$.

Those two facts immediately imply that any automorphism fixes the element of the prime field.

Comment: I see that the result follows from the two bullet points but I don't see why they are true? For the first how do we know $0,1$ are sent to themselves? Is this because it is a homomorphism of fields? Also because of the second bullet point why is this true I haven't seen this result before.

Comment: $f(0)=0$ und $f(1)=1$ by definition of a homomorphism in the category of unital rings. The second bullet is just reformulation of what you already said: The prime field is the smalles subfield of $K$.

Comment: Okay I get the first bullet point now could you try and explain intuitively why the prime subfield is equal to the intersection of all subfields? I don't see this?

Comment: Whats your definition of a prime subfield?

Comment: The smallest subfield of a field. Is it because every family of subfields is a subfield so we can't possible get anything smaller than this?

Comment: 'The smallest subfield' is just another term for 'the intersection of all subfields', isn't it? Of course, to even justify the term 'smallest subfield', you have to note that the intersection of subfields is again a subfield.